# How can I add State and Country attribute for customer in Admin, Magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, custom-attributes, registration, custom-field

I need to create State and Country attribute for customer registration and Admin.

How can I Achieving State and Country field functionality in Admin under customer Account Information

Answer (score 0):

State and country should already be listed under **Customers -> {Any Customer} -> Addresses** in the Admin panel.

On the registration form however, I have noticed Magento has no setting to enable address form on the customer registration page. In `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` on line 45, you can see there is an if statement wrapped around your address form.

```
<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset address">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
              ...
        <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
    </fieldset>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Copy this template to your own theme and you can either remove the if statement or set the condition to true.

Comment: I need them on admin >> customer >>Additional information  I have created custom country and state field in front end registration referring to the link https://magecomp.com/blog/create-country-state-dropdown-in-magento-2-custom-frontend-form/  , I need the functionality on admin, Right now I can see the custom fields but cant implement the functionality when country is selected it list only the state and if no option is there text field shows.